# Giving .yaml file as $ref in my swagger.json

Tags: json, yaml, swagger

I have a swagger.json file, when I am configuring my parameters and schema I need to give reference to some .yaml files via $ref. Can swagger automatically resolve that or do I need any conversion or something?

I read this link but I didn't see:
[relevant link](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/)

Comment: they need to be the same format.  json can reference json files and yaml can ref yaml files, they can't be used together.